# Changing int to double changes my result to zero

Tags: c

If I leave all variables  as int I get 32. The division is supposed to give me 32.5 so I thought that changing everything to double would do it, but it just gives me zero...

Here is the code (everything in int):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, int *average);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tableau[4] = {30, 50, 50};
    int *x = 0;
    int *average = 0;
    const int tailleTab = 4;

    sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);

    printf("The average is %d\n", average);

    return 0;
}

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, int *average)
{
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0 ; i < tailleTableau ; i++)
  {
  *x = *x + tableau[i];
  }
  *average = *x/tailleTableau;

}
```

So this works and gives me 32... Now if I change everything to double and %d to %f in the printf function, it gives me zero and I don't understand why...

Comment: No need to make anything but `average` a double, apart from casting either the dividend or the divisor.

Comment: you don't get any warnings from your compiler with this code?

Comment: No, I didnt get any warnings.. Should I?

Comment: @TimurRidjanovic please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you the most

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is lots of mistakes in your code. I corrected all of them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, double *average);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tableau[4] = {30, 50, 50};
    int x = 0;
    double average = 0;
    const int tailleTab = 4;

    sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);

    printf("The average is %lf\n", average);

    return 0;
}

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, double *average)
{
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0 ; i < tailleTableau ; i++)
  {
  *x = *x + tableau[i];
  }
  *average = (double)(*x)/(double)tailleTableau;

}
```

Comment: Learning is good!..note all the positions where I made changes in your code...also read answer posted by others..Good-Luck

Answer (score 2):

One of your problems lies here:

```
int *x = 0;
int *average = 0;

sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);
```

Those first two lines should be:

```
int x = 0;
int average = 0;
```

This is evident from the warnings you should be getting, assuming you're using a decent compiler:

```
qq.c: In function ‘main’:
qq.c:13: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘sommeTableau’ from incompatible pointer type
qq.c:4: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
qq.c:13: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘sommeTableau’ from incompatible pointer type
qq.c:4: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
```

In addition, you don't need _everything to be a double, just the average, so you should only change the type of that variable and match that with the parameters passed to the function.

It will also be necessary to cast the total `*x` to a double before doing the division, so that it knows you don't mean integer division.

With those changes, the output changes from:

```
The average is 4.000000
```

(for me) to the correct:

```
The average is 32.500000
```

See the following program for more detail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, double *average) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < tailleTableau ; i++)
        *x = *x + tableau[i];
    *average = ((double)(*x))/tailleTableau;
}

int main (void) {
    int tableau[4] = {30, 50, 50};
    int x = 0;
    double average = 0;
    const int tailleTab = 4;

    sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);
    printf("The average is %lf\n", average);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing x and average as null pointer. Thats why your code is giving segmentation fault.

As per you describtion please check(http://codepad.org/z8fVUTe5).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, int *average);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tableau[4] = {30, 50, 50};
    int x = 0;
    int average = 0;
    const int tailleTab = 4;

    sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);

    printf("The average is %d\n", average);

    return 0;
}

void sommeTableau(int tableau[], int tailleTableau, int *x, int *average)
{
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0 ; i < tailleTableau ; i++)
  {
  *x = *x + tableau[i];
  }
  *average = *x/tailleTableau;

}
```

Output:-

> The average is 32

Answer (score 1):

Something is terribly wrong here -- you're defining `x` and `average` as pointer variables in `main`, which if you are lucky is the same size as an `int`, but may result in undefined behavior.

Remove the `*` from the local variable declarations of `x` and `average` in `main` and it may actually work.

Also, in `sommeTableau`, both operands of the division (`*x` and `tailleTableau`) are `int`, so integer division is performed and the remainder discarded prior to assignment to `*average`.

Comment: I just changed average to double and put %lf in the printf function, and it still gave me a zero.

Comment: @TimurRidjanovic Never mind, that isn't the problem, it's the declaration of `x` and `average`.

Comment: Ok, I did that and it gave me 32.0000 .How come I'm not getting 32.5?

Comment: If both operands of a division are integer, the division is performed in integer arithmetic and the remainder is discarded.  It doesn't matter that the result is being assigned to a floating-point variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *x = 0;
int *average = 0;
```

This is defining two *pointers* and setting the *pointers* to zero -- which, in a pointer context translates to a null pointer. So, you have to pointers to nothing.

```
sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);
```

Here, you're passing the *addresses* of those pointers to the function, so the function is really receiving an `int **`.

```
printf("The average is %d\n", average);
```

This is then taking the value of the pointer -- the address its holding -- and (probably) treating that bit pattern as an `int`. This is technically undefined behavior, but on many machines, a pointer it enough like an int for it to appear to work. The same will almost *never* be true with a floating point number though.

What you want to do here is define two `int`s (or two `double`s) and pass their addresses to your function:

```
double x=0.0, average=0.0;

sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);

// ...
printf("%f, %f\n", x, average);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually work.

Here you define `x` and `average` as `NULL` pointers to `int`:

```
int *x = 0;
int *average = 0;
```

And here instead of pointers to `int` you pass pointers to pointers to `int`:

```
sommeTableau(tableau, tailleTab, &x, &average);
```

Which is clearly wrong. You should enable compiler warnings to see such problematic places and correct them.

Here the correction would be:

```
int x = 0;
int average = 0;
```

Now, here:

```
printf("The average is %d\n", average);
```

You are lying to `printf()` about what you're going to give it (an `int`, because of `%d`), but you're actually giving it a pointer to `int`. The above correction fixes this. If you lie to `printf()` about the type of some parameter, anything can happen. If your compiler is `gcc` and you enable warnings, you can spot this kind of problems as well.